# Using ':nth-of-type' Selects all Child Elements Together, Not Individually

Tags: html, css

I'm used to `nth-of-type` selecting an element within the element (owning the class) I placed the pseudo-class on. For example; `body div:nth-of-type(24)`, to my knowledge, would select the twenty-fourth `div` in the `body` of my page.

However, I've found something odd happening when I try to utilize this.

Here's my HTML:

```
            <div class="page-projects">

            <p>Projects</p>
            <div>
                <a href="http://www.projects.crowes.co/biotechgames">
                    <button>
                        <img src="../assets/pro/cro-biotechlogo.png" />
                        <p>BioTech Games</p>
                    </button>
                </a>
                <a href="http://www.projects.crowes.co/moonsquads/preview/">
                    <button>
                        <img src="../assets/pro/cro-moonsquadslogo.png" />
                        <p>Moonsquads</p>
                    </button>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

If I try to target the first button (under the `a` of `http://www.projects.crowes.co/biotechgames`), I should use `.page-projects div:nth-of-type(1) button:nth-of-type(1)` and then enter whatever attributes I like, say `border: 1px solid red` -- this should change that first `<button`'s border to `1px` of `solid red`, but instead, it changes both that button and the next one (the one with an `a` under `http://www.projects.crowes.co/moonsquads/preview/`).

I find then that the second button itself can't be individually targetted. My CSS selector targets all buttons as if they are the first type of `button` element under the child `div` of `page-projects`.

Am I doing this wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a JSFiddle to explain it : [see it here](https://jsfiddle.net/4foo7v52/)

```
.page-projects div:nth-of-type(1) a:nth-of-type(1) button {border: 1px solid red}
```

You have to put `a:nth-of-type` to select the first a tag and then you can select the first button of it, which is the only one.

Otherwise, with your condition, it will select all the first `<button>` that valid the condition, because there is only one `div` element in your .page-projects class.